# Publicação de Aplicação Symfony (produção)

Tags: php, framework, symfony

Olá,
Sou novo no desenvolvimento em Symfony e estou publicando uma aplicação pela primeira vez em uma hospedagem na hostgator.
Estou utilizando a versão 5.2.

Já adicionei os arquivos do projeto a hospedagem, já instalei as dependências via composer porém quando acesso o projeto ele lista todos os arquivos do diretório e não executa o projeto como deveria. Se eu clicar na plasta public ele carrega a home.

Abaixo segue como aparece ao acessarmos o projeto.

Agradeço desde-já pela ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema no hostgator.
Fiz o seguinte: criei dois .htaccess. Um na raiz e um em public

.htaccess na Raiz:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

.htaccess em public:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```